# xss injection in numberfield of paging toolbar in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs-grid

I am having a security issue with extjs 6 paging toolbar for grid. i am able to inject xss script in numberfield of paging toolbar.

Following is the fiddle with a paging grid.
[grid Fiddle link](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1vi6)

try pasting this code in the paging toolbar input field to replicate the issue : 
    `<img src=-x onerror="alert (0)";/>`

I wish to stop this xss injection. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

one way to fix it is by changing the paging bar's numberfield input type to number. You'll have access to numberfield dom in afterrender.

```
dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            store: 'simpsonsStore', // same store GridPanel is using
            dock: 'bottom',
            displayInfo: true,
            listeners:{
                afterrender:function(pg){
                   pg.child('[xtype=numberfield]').getEl().dom.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].type='number';
                }
            }
        }]
```

Answer (score 0):

One option: 
The paging toolbar consists of a numberfield.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.1/classic/src/Paging.js.html

Add a listener to this field and check the input before processing.

Comment: i am unable to figure out which event to listen. Can you try updating the fiddle. The alert is displayed on pasting the code in the numberfield and before sending the data for processing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for masking alphabets as number field will only contain number only.Check this.

Comment: Can you please update the fiddle and share it. As the issue is happening during pasting of the code.